# Not Cauchy Proof By Definition

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

How do I prove that $\{n\}$ is not Cauchy?

So far, this is what I have so far:

Let $ε=0.$ Let N ∈ ℕ be given. Assume $n,m ≥ N$ and $|X_{n+1}-X_n|=|N+1-N|=1>\epsilon .$ Thus $\{n\}$ is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon=1$. Fix $p\in\mathbb N$. Then, if you take $m=p$ and $n=p+1$, then $m,n\geqslant p$ and $|x_m-x_n|=1\geqslant\varepsilon$.

What you did is wrong, because it is part of the definition of Cauchy sequence that $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I think setting $\epsilon =1/2$ would make the argument more clear.

Comment: @Joel But then wouldn't   |X_m−X_n| < ε which would make it cauchy?

Comment: @Liza No. If $\epsilon=\frac12$, then $m\neq n\implies|X_m-X_n|=1>\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok thanks--that makes sense.